# How to add indexing in mongoid to a referenced model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a **Answer** model referenced to a **User** and **Choice** model.

```
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :choice
end
```

I am trying to add indexing to the **Answer** model.
In Mysql it looks like this:

```
add_index :answers, [:choice_id, :user_id], unique: true
```

I went through the mongoid documentation. The mongo way to achieve same thing would be (Just trying)

```
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user, index: true
  belongs_to :choice, index: true
end
```

And then to run `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`

Is this right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Its right if the docs say so. Did you try it locally?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add the `index` method in the model class to have compound indexes as follows:

```
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user, index: true
  belongs_to :choice, index: true

  index({ choice_id: 1, user_id: 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

`index: true` for the defined attribute, just create indexes for that particular field.

Now, indexes will be generated for newly created records. And you can populate the indexes for old records by running this command:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

If you want to populate indexes for only `Answer` model collections, run this command from console:

```
Answer.create_indexes
```

See [mongoid documentation](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html) for more details.

Hope it helps !